# How to pass zap session files to dockerized zap scanner?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, owasp, zap

How to properly pass session files (.session .session.data .session.properties .session.script and context) to the following command before the scan is executed?

```
docker run -rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py \
-t https://www.example.com -r testreport.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to?

It is (probably) possible, but it wont do anything useful. The ZAP baseline scan spiders the target you specify, so supplying an existing ZAP session file wont help you. Unless I'm missing something ;)

Comment: Scan configs in the scan policy, in the additional files are endpoints and other parameters from what they have told me they need

Answer (score 0):

Use the `core/action/loadSession/` API endpoint. Something like this:

```
from zapv2 import ZAPv2 as zap
import time

apikey = 'apikey12345' #Change this to match your setup
z = zap(apikey=apikey, proxies={'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:9999', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:9999'})
time.sleep(5)

print 'start..'
z.core.load_session('/root/Download/zaptmp/test.session') #Obviously this needs to be your session path

sites = z.core.sites

# Check that the session loaded... I'm printing, you could check count not zero, whatever
print 'Listing sites in loaded session:'
for site in sites:
    print site
```

Comment: That of course assumes that loading a session is actually what you're after. But per Simon's response below perhaps it's not.