# ZAP CLI active scan from session files

Tags: zap

Background: I created session files with the daemon in headless mode by running ZAP OWASP as a proxy on the server itself (so I get an exhaustive test by our teams of testers without asking all of them to change their proxy settings).

Now, after copying those session files back to my computer, I can open the GUI, do File -> Open Session
This adds my website and all the targets.
I can now right click on it and do "attack -> active scan".

So the question is:
=> How do I do the same from CLI ? ie: run an "active scan" on CLI based on those session files ?

In case it might help, the end goal is to:

1. run the daemon regularly on our test environment to populate session files
2. use those sessions files in our CI/CD

ps: this is kind of a duplicate of [How to pass zap session files to dockerized zap scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52077472/how-to-pass-zap-session-files-to-dockerized-zap-scanner/52077875#52077875) , but because the question was vague, there were no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I found part of the solution shortly after asking the question...
In short, launch zap in headless and launch the scan from cli after loading the session

```
# Launch zap:
docker run --rm --name zap -u zap -p 8080:8080 -v "$(pwd)/reports":/zap/reports/:rw -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config api.disablekey=true

# Load the session (assuming the session was copied to $(pwd)/reports)
docker exec zap zap-cli session load /zap/reports/session/session.session

# Launch the scan:
docker exec zap zap-cli --verbose active-scan https://<MYSITE>
```

However, running from GUI, this active scan takes a long time (more than 30min) and scans all urls; while the CLI scan seems to only scan the https:// and exits

Comment: FYI the zap-cli is a 3rd party tool and not supported by the ZAP core team. We recommend either using the ZAP packages scans https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/ or calling the ZAP API directly (using the urls or one of the supported API clients). FYI we are working on a new ZAP automation framework which will be launched soon.

Comment: Thanks @SimonBennetts - would you know how to accomplish what I need via the ZAP API ?

Comment: We have lots of API docs here :) https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#introduction